# Can a full matrix algebra over a field have a basis of nilpotent elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I can see that the standard base is not of nilpotent element (the elements on the diagonal are not), but can't prove that proposition, or be sure it is even true.

Comment: What standard basis?

Comment: by standard basis I mean the matrices with 1 at index i,j, and 0 anywhere else

Comment: I somehow missed the matrix part. Please edit the question so that the full question is there and not just in the title.

Comment: Do you mean $M_n(\mathbb{F})$, the algebra of *all* matrices over $\mathbb{F}$? Because "matrix algebra" usually allows subalgebras of these, and in some of these subalgebras (such as those consisting of strictly upper triangular matrices), *all* elements are nilpotent.

Comment: @CalvinLin I think it's pretty clear: can you find $n^2$ linearly independent nilpotent matrices that span $M_n(F)$?

Comment: I think Matt Pressland's right that the OP is thinking of the full matrix ring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"No" because of the following hints I'm giving you here.

The trace of a nilpotent matrix is zero. What do you know about the traces of $A+B$ and $\lambda A$ for matrices $A,B$ and scalar $\lambda$?

This should make it clear that you won't be able to generate just any matrix with a linear combination of nilpotent matrices.

Comment: thanks. even easier: one element of the basis must have a non zero field element on the diagonal, so it's not nilpotent

Comment: @user57076 No, that is false logic. The matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}$ is nilpotent.